# How to export HDFS data into mysql?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

i wanted to export HDFS data into mysql .
i did something which i have given below, and i'm getting these may errors.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://vamshhi-Inspiron-N5010:3306/hadoop --username root --password root --table BankDetails --input-fields-terminated-by ','  --export-dir /user/vamshhi/BankOut001


Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.Warning: 
$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.15/12/01 11:17:37 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting 
your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/12/01 11:17:37 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQLstreaming resultset.
15/12/01 11:17:37 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/12/01 11:17:37 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:683)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:223)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:347)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1277)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1089)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 32 more
15/12/01 11:17:37 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
```

How can i get out of here? i have imported mysql-connector into sqoop home folder till i am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbc:mysql://vamshhi-Inspiron-N5010:3306/hadoop
```

Error says connection time out and you are using above JDBC URL.

Troubleshooting steps:

- Check connectivity `ping vamshhi-Inspiron-N5010`
- Check whether database is running on specified port 
  `telnet vamshhi-Inspiron-N5010 3306`

If first one is failing then you are not able to connect to specified host.
If first is successful and second one is failing then mysql database is not running.

You can learn more on the topic in my [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8q5X0ZBeUaK1yl_TP-tJInC)